# Python: How to winsorize the Mean and Standard Deviation?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a code that I use for multiple different metrics (e.g. Value at Risk, Omega, Sortino, etc.). The formula I use for the average is:

Mean (average):

```
e = numpy.mean(r)

return numpy.mean(diff) / vol(diff)
```

Standard deviation:

```
return numpy.std(returns)
```

I would like to winsorize the means (and standard deviations) that are used in my calculations. Can anyone advise how to do it? I have found this part but am not really sure how to implement it (if this is it of course):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
import os
import numpy as np

from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize

file_location = input("path to file: ")
dirname = os.path.dirname(file_location)
filename = os.path.basename(file_location)

with open(file_location, 'r') as readfile, \
        open(os.path.join(dirname, 'win_' + filename), 'w') as writefile1, \
        open(os.path.join(dirname, 'mod_' + filename), 'w') as writefile2:
    writefile1.write('adj_mean,adj_std\n')
    for idx, line in enumerate(readfile):
        print("Reading line# {}...".format(idx))
        series = np.array([float(x) for x in line.split(',')])
        print("Read {} values...".format(len(series)))
        winsorized_series = winsorize(series, limits=[0.10, 0.10])
        print("Writing modified series to file...")
        writefile2.write(','.join(map(str, winsorized_series)) + '\n')
        adj_mean = np.mean(winsorized_series)
        adj_std = np.std(winsorized_series)
        print("adj mean and std dev...")
        writefile1.write("{},{}\n".format(adj_mean, adj_std))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a precise answer, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is needed.

Presuming 'e' is an nparray

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize

e = np.random.rand(1,100)
print("{}".format(e))
winsorize(e, limits=(0.25,0.25), inplace=True)
print("{}".format(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize

def winsorized_mean(x, ql, qr):
    return np.mean(winsorize(x, limits=(ql, qr))

def winsorized_std(x, ql, qr):
    return np.std(winsorize(x, limits=(ql, qr))
```